# Destructor crash on application close windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a class that is assigning itself to an event:

```
public MainMenuButton()
{
     this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MainMenuButton);
     (App.Current as App).ApplicationLanguageChange += Localize;
}
```

And on destructor i do this:

```
~MainMenuButton()
{
    (App.Current as App).ApplicationLanguageChange -= Localize;
}
```

When on emulator i do a longpress on back button and close the app - the destructor throws an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   myapplication.WindowsPhone.exe
>
> Additional information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When on emulator i do a longpress on back button and close the app -
> the destructor throws an error

You cannot access any managed resources from a finalizer. There is no guarantee that any of them will still be alive. If all you're doing is de-registering from an event, you don't need that finalizer at all, as your app is about to close anyway.

[The docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Finalize operations have the following limitations:
>
> - The exact time when the finalizer executes is undefined. To ensure
>   deterministic release of resources for instances of your class,
>   implement a Close method or provide a IDisposable.Dispose
>   implementation.
> - The finalizers of two objects are not guaranteed to
>   run in any specific order, even if one object refers to the other.
>   That is, if Object A has a reference to Object B and both have
>   finalizers, Object B might have already been finalized when the
>   finalizer of Object A starts.
> - The thread on which the finalizer runs
>   is unspecified.